# Displaying objects of custom templated abstract data type

Tags: c++, class, templates, visual-c++, abstract-data-type

I am developing an abstract data type that is similar to the map STL for an assignment. The brief says I should provide a range of facilities, including outputting objects contained in the abstract data type. How would I go about outputting an array data stored in the ADT, I can't use any STL so I presume I can't use iterators, and having a function that uses cout in the ADT seems silly. Any suggestions? Thanks. Code below:

```
template <typename K, typename D>
class Map
{
private:
int mapSize;
int dataFilled;
struct keyData
{
    K key;
    D data;
};

keyData* datas;
keyData* ptr;
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't use the standard library? Any of it? What about `std::cout` or `std::ostream`?

Comment: @Jefffrey I'm not sure if it's okay to use cout in a member function of the STL

Comment: of my ADT I should say, don't know if ADT's should contain external stuff like that

Comment: You need to provide an overloaded `operator<<` for your type.

Comment: Is there no way I can use some kind of iterators?

Comment: In the way iterators are used to display vectors, like having a custom one for my class

Comment: You can use whatever you want (and allowed to) inside your `operator<<`. If you are writing a container-like class you probably need to define your own iterator types. You then can use them in your `operator<<`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go the way of letting the user access the objects, then I would go with iterators and `operator[]`. To define iterators you simply need to define a `begin` and `end` member function (with eventual `const` overloads). The problem is that you generally want to offer both keys and values of the map. The way `std::map` solves this is by returning some type that is semantically equivalent to a pointer to `std::pair<const Key, T>` so that you can access the key via `std::get<0>(*it)` and the value by `std::get<1>(*it)`.

If you want to define a custom "print" function you can simply define `operator<<` for `std::ostream`:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Map<Key, Value>&) { ... }
```

This way you'll be able to use:

```
Map<Key, Value> map;
std::cout << map;
```

I'd recommend providing, in a similar fashion, also an `operator>>` for `std::istream`.

For more inspiration you can take a [look at the `std::map` interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: @Yakk True. It returns something that is *semantically equivalent* to a pair of `Key` and `Value`.